# Justification of using >>

Tags: monads, state-monad, haskell

In Real World Haskell [chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html), they give justification for `(>>)` like this:

> We use this function when we want to perform actions in a certain order, but don't care what the result of one is.

They then give an nice example demonstrating it:

```
ghci > print "foo" >> print "bar"
"foo"
"bar"
```

Later on the chapter they use the same concept for generating random values in the State monad:

```
getRandom :: Random a => RandomState a
getRandom =
  get >>= \gen ->
  let (val, gen') = random gen in
  put gen' >>
  return val
```

But why in this case they are using the statement `put gen' >>` when ultimately they are ignoring it's output value. Why can't the above function be something like this:

```
getRandom :: Random a => RandomState a
getRandom =
  get >>= \gen ->
  let (val, gen') = random gen in
  return val
```

Just for completion of this question, I'm adding up the associated type definitions and functions for the above context:

```
newtype State s a = State {
  runState :: s -> (a, s)
  }

get :: State s s
get = State $ \s -> (s, s)

put :: s -> State s ()
put s = State $ \_ -> ((), s)

type RandomState a = State StdGen a
```

Comment: in your code block below "why can't the function be like this", where did the `put` go?

Comment: Note that the random monad is also in [a dedicated library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom). The putting of the updated generators is usually done automatically as it should be, but it _needs_ to be done if you don't want just a stream of a single constant value. On higher levels, you'll only ever use `getRandom` and don't need to care about how it passes on the generator. — But of course there are appications where you actually need explicit side effects with no useful return value. Generally you'll use `do` notation though, so `>>` does indeed not turn up very often.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `put` has a side effect. It sticks something into the state monad that can be accessed and modified later.

It's return value is just `()` which is boring, so we don't care about it, but we certainly want to make sure we put the new random generator into the state.

Think of it like this, the state monad is really a function `s -> (a, s)`. and `put` is

```
put s = \oldState -> (() , s)
```

So this has a side effect, it's throwing away the old state and replacing it. Consider this example

```
  test = put 1 >> get >>= \x -> put 2 >> get >>= \y -> return (x, y)

  -- or with do notation
  test' = do
    put 1
    x <- get
    put 2
    y <- get
    return (x, y)
```

Here `x` is `1` and `y` is `2`. Clearly put has interesting effects beyond just it's return value.

Comment: I think it should be like this: `put s = \oldState -> ((), s)`

Comment: @Sibi Yeah, I had it flopped `(a, s)` vs `(s, a)`. The point is a little orthogonal though.